# Angularjs watch and count http get results not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

First time to ask a question. Hope can get problem resolved. Thank you!

```
app.controller('add_comment', function($scope, $http,toastr,$stateParams) {

    //count is for watching users posting new comments
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.$watch('count', function() {
        $http.get("/reports/showcomment/"+$stateParams.reportId).then(function (response) {
            $scope.commentlists = response.data;
        })
    },true);



    $scope.insertdata=function(){
        $http.post("/reports/comment",{'comment':$scope.htmlcontent,'report_id':$scope.report_id})
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    if(response.data=="评论成功"){
                        toastr.success(response.data);
                        ++$scope.count;
                        //$scope.commentlists.push({'comment':$scope.htmlcontent,'researcher':'#{user}'});
                        $scope.htmlcontent ='';
                    }
                    else{
                        toastr.warning("评论失败");

                    }
                }
                ,function errorCallback(response){
                    toastr.warning("评论失败");
                }
            )
    }
    });

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div ng-controller="add_comment" class="thumbnail comment_list">
      <div style="padding: 9px 9px 0 9px;" class="caption">
        <table style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="padding: 4px;">
                <p class="fa fa-comments tabletitle"> 评论</p>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="comments in commentlists">
              <td><a href="/researcher/{{comments.researcher}}" style="color: #337ab7;">{{ comments.researcher + ':'}}</a>
                <div style="float:right">{{ comments.time}}</div>
                <div ng-bind-html="comments.comment" style="padding-top:10px;word-wrap: break-all;-ms-word-break: break-all;word-break: break-all;-webkit-hyphens: auto;-moz-hyphens: auto;-ms-hyphens: auto;hyphens: auto;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <form name="add_comment">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled="disabled"></div>
              <input type="hidden" name="report_id" ng-value="report_id=report_content._id"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div style="float:right;margin-top:5px" class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
              <button ng-click="insertdata()" style="width: 100%;padding:10px;margin-bottom: 3%;" class="btn btn-success">提交评论</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in Firefox and chrome. But when I use Microsoft edge as well as newest IE, every time i post a comment. `$http.get("/reports/showcomment/"+$stateParams.reportId)` do not append the new comment I just post. But in DB, the post is actually successful. All the problems are IE/edge not append the new post.

Comment: Please edit the question to update code.  Putting it in the comments makes it hard to understand the question.

Comment: Hi, revised already